# Combine an index from one Pandas DataFrame with a different index in a different Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Pandas newbie here so this may be a fairly basic and easy question.

I want to combine the data from one index in one DataFrame into a different index in a different DataFrame.

In the below example, I've split the data into a DataFrame of verified indexes (*MainTable*) and a DataFrame of erroneous indexes (*ErrorTable*).

After manually reviewing the erroneous entries in *ErrorTable*, I want to be able merge the data from *ErrorTable*'s '**Cta**' and '**Mice**' entries into *MainTable*'s '**Cat**' and '**Mouse**' entries.

```
import pandas as pd
RawData = pd.DataFrame({'Number sighted today':[4, 3, 1, 2, 8, 3],
                        'Number sighted yesterday':[5, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0]},
                       index = ['Dog', 'Cat', 'Cta', 'Mouse', 'Ant', 'Mice'])

AllowedIndexes = ['Dog','Cat','Mouse','Ant']

MainTable = RawData[RawData.index.isin(AllowedIndexes) == True]
ErrorTable = RawData[RawData.index.isin(AllowedIndexes) == False]
```

[image: MainTable and ErrorTable image]

---

---

I have tried:

```
MainTable.loc['Cat'] = MainTable.loc['Cat'] + ErrorTable.loc['Cta']
MainTable.loc['Mouse'] = MainTable.loc['Mouse'] + ErrorTable.loc['Mice']
```

And while it technically works, it keeps throwing up a warning message that I'm doing something wrong which I haven't been unable to understand, so I figure there must be a more stable way to do this.

[image: Error Message image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you mean an elementwise addition, this could look like this:

```
MainTable.loc['Mouse', :] += ErrorTable.loc['Mice', :]
MainTable.loc['Cat', :] += ErrorTable.loc['Cta', :]

>>> MainTable
       Number sighted today  Number sighted yesterday
Dog                       4                         5
Cat                       4                         1
Mouse                     5                         2
Ant                       8                         1
```

Comment: What do you mean with 'combine'?

Comment: Thanks, this seems to do the job too. 

I'm still getting the big red scary SettingWithCopy warning that I don't understand. Would be grateful if anybody could explain it to me in layman's terms.

Comment: The warning comes from the different type of slicing. It seems to be that `MainTable.loc['Cat']` creates a copy and this copy is stored in a dummy variable. If your work with this dummy, the warning appears. To avoid this, use the `:` which means all values.

Comment: I added .copy() to the end of the original MainTable and ErrorTable declaration statements and that seems to have sorted out the warning! https://www.dataquest.io/blog/settingwithcopywarning/